# move specific values (based on that value) in each list of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, move

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
list= [[0,1,0,0,0][0,0,0,2,0],...,[0,0,10,0,0]]
```

What i would like as the output, is to have all the values (1,2..,10) to move to the beginning of the list they are in, so something like :

```
list= [[1,0,0,0,0][2,0,0,0,0],...,[10,0,0,0,0]]
```

I have tried  :

```
new_list= list.insert(0, list.pop(list.index(value)))
```

which works for one list, but I want to do it for all the lists inside the list.

Comment: use `sorted()`-- `print(list(map(lambda x: sorted(x, reverse=True), lst)))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort:

```
l = [[0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,0],[0,0,10,0,0]]
print([sorted(i, reverse=True) for i in l])
```

Output:

```
[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [2, 0, 0, 0, 0], [10, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply, but what if the values are not numbers, like they are words?